# My bootstrap popover doesn't trigger the event-defined function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I would like to show you a jQuery/bootstrap code. I extract the needed code in a jsfiddle : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BMnz9/). The behavior is:

1. Run the jsfiddle project
2. mouse over on the ipsum text
3. on the displayed bootstrap popover, click on "show more >>" link
4. the function on click is trigger and a new window 800x600 is displayed
5. close this window
6. goto step 2.
7. instead of step 4., the function is not triggered and a new tab is open instead

I do want the function be triggered each time the user click on "show more >>".

I am quite sure that the javascript code is the problem: scope, variables, conflicts... I don't know.

Do you have an opinion or advice or good practice on what is going wrong?

[The demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/BMnz9/).
The function I tell about is :

```
function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var width  = 800,
        height = 600,
        left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
        top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
        url    = this.href;
    var opts   = 'status=1' +
                 ',width='  + width  +
                 ',height=' + height +
                 ',top='    + top    +
                 ',left='   + left;
    window.open(url, 'manual', opts);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is "simple".

First, you have a function "formatPopoverContent" that generate the popover html content. Your bind the click event in here.

The problem is that function is executed once, but the popover generated by bootstrap create the popover div and insert it in the DOM on the fly (when you hover, the div is created, and on mouse out the div is removed from DOM).
And in your function you bind the click event using cordialManualLink.on('click', …) where cordialManualLink is the  created for the first time by the function, but then removed by the popover (I don't konw if I'm very clear…). And the way you bind the event, newly created elements are not bound.

That's why in your fiddle, not only when you click for the 2nd time, if you hover, then mouseout, then hover again (whithout clicking a first time), you won't get a new window.

The solution is to "live" bind the click event so even if new elements are created, they'll get bound.

So the solution is to simply do :

```
$(document).on('click', cordialManualLink, …);
```

instead of

```
cordialManualLink.on('click', …);
```

Comment: Can I bind several event like `$(document).on('click', showMoreLink, myFunction);` and `$(document).on('click', anotherLinkInPopover, anotherFunction);` etc.?

Comment: On the updated jsfiddle, the function is triggered wherever the user click, even on a blank part of the page. Do I do something wrong?

Comment: Yes you can bind multiple elements to any events this way. $(document).on(event, selector, handler()); is the new way to use the depracated live function, which allows you to _"Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."_ ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/))
When I go to the jsfiddle, I still see the first version :/

Comment: The updated version is there : http://jsfiddle.net/BMnz9/1/
And I am finding out that it is the selector which is used the wrong way. I must select my DOM element to be binded by a class name more than the jQuery object... Am I right?

Comment: Yes you're right, my bad, didn't really paid attention on what cordialManualLink was. jQuery's on() expect the 2nd argument to be a selector. Here it's an element built on the fly with jQuery so it may indeed not work. If you add a class (or use a revelant selector pointing to your <a>) and use it as selector for on(), it should be OK.